# How to create marbles with the marbles02 chaincode on peer0 Org1 and on peer0 Org2?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have set up data persistence in the peer and the couchdb containers and have run through the commands with the marbles02 chaincode manually on peer0 Org1 in the cli container (with the command line commented in docker-compose-cli.yaml) without problem.  The marbles are created and I can query them from both peer0 Org1 and peer0 Org2.  However, when I create marbles on peer0 Org2, it seems that the initMarble function works but the marble is not really created.  It does not exist in the couchdb and I cannot read it using the chaincode on peer0 Org1 or peer0 Org2.

How can I create marbles with the marbles02 chaincode on peer0 Org2?  Thank You!

Ubuntu version:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.10
Release:    17.10
Codename:   artful
```

Hyperledger Fabric version:

```
x86_64-1.1.0-preview
```

All actions below are done with the "first-network" (byfn.sh) example:

Configuration Changes:

added the following lines in the volumes sections in docker-compose-base.yaml for peer container data persistence

```
for peer0.org1.example.com:
    - ../persist-data/peer0org1:/var/hyperledger/production
for peer1.org1.example.com:
    - ../persist-data/peer1org1:/var/hyperledger/production
for peer0.org2.example.com:
    - ../persist-data/peer0org2:/var/hyperledger/production
for peer1.org2.example.com:
    - ../persist-data/peer1org2:/var/hyperledger/production
```

added the following lines in the volumes sections in docker-compose-couch.yaml for couchdb container data persistence

```
for couchdb0:
    - ./persist-data/couchdb0:/opt/couchdb/data
for couchdb1:
    - ./persist-data/couchdb1:/opt/couchdb/data
for couchdb2:
    - ./persist-data/couchdb2:/opt/couchdb/data
for couchdb3:
    - ./persist-data/couchdb3:/opt/couchdb/data
```

I have also changed to couchdb port numbers as follow to avoid conflicts with the couchdb installed on my computer:

```
for couchdb0:
  - "6984:5984"
for couchdb1:
  - "7984:5984"
for couchdb2:
  - "8984:5984"
for couchdb3:
  - "9984:5984"
```

Actions and commands:

```
cd to the first-network directory
../../bin/cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD
../../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block
export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel  && ../../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME
../../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel-artifacts/Org1MSPanchors.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME -asOrg Org1MSP
../../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel-artifacts/Org2MSPanchors.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME -asOrg Org2MSP
docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml -f docker-compose-couch.yaml up -d
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org1MSP"
CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt

# enter the cli container and execute the commands in the cli container manually
docker exec -it cli bash
export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel
peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
peer channel join -b mychannel.block
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051 CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP" CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt peer channel join -b mychannel.block
peer channel update -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/Org1MSPanchors.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051 CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP" CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt peer channel update -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/Org2MSPanchors.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem

peer chaincode install -n marbles -v 1.0 -p github.com/chaincode/marbles02/go
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051 CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP" CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt peer chaincode install -n marbles -v 1.0 -p github.com/chaincode/marbles02/go

peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n marbles -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init"]}' -P "OR ('Org0MSP.member','Org1MSP.member')"

peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050  --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n marbles -c '{"Args":["initMarble","marble1","blue","35","tom"]}'
peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050  --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n marbles -c '{"Args":["initMarble","marble2","red","50","tom"]}'
peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050  --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n marbles -c '{"Args":["initMarble","marble3","blue","70","tom"]}'

# The output of the 2 following commands on peer0 Org1 is at the bottom

peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n marbles -c '{"Args":["readMarble","marble1"]}'
peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n marbles -c '{"Args":["getMarblesByRange","marble","marble9"]}'

# The output of the 2 following commands on peer0 Org2 is at the bottom

CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051 CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP" CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n marbles -c '{"Args":["readMarble","marble1"]}'
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051 CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP" CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n marbles -c '{"Args":["getMarblesByRange","marble","marble9"]}'

# The output of the following initMarble command is at the bottom

CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051 CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP" CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050  --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n marbles -c '{"Args":["initMarble","marble4","red","40","john"]}'

# The output of the 2 following commands on peer0 Org1 is at the bottom

peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n marbles -c '{"Args":["readMarble","marble1"]}'
peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n marbles -c '{"Args":["getMarblesByRange","marble","marble9"]}'

# The output of the 2 following commands on peer0 Org2 is at the bottom

CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051 CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP" CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n marbles -c '{"Args":["readMarble","marble1"]}'
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051 CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP" CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n marbles -c '{"Args":["getMarblesByRange","marble","marble9"]}'
```

Output of the first two queries on peer0 Org1:

```
root@370bc984a456:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n marbles -c '{"Args":["readMarble","marble1"]}'
2018-01-26 17:51:22.809 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2018-01-26 17:51:22.809 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-01-26 17:51:22.809 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 003 Using default escc
2018-01-26 17:51:22.809 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 004 Using default vscc
2018-01-26 17:51:22.809 UTC [chaincodeCmd] getChaincodeSpec -> DEBU 005 java chaincode disabled
2018-01-26 17:51:22.810 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 006 Sign: plaintext: 0AAE070A6A08031A0C089AD5ADD30510...644D6172626C650A076D6172626C6531 
2018-01-26 17:51:22.810 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 007 Sign: digest: 4F366060889A2856285FC243DC170DE5EF24C3215156DAAA0CF61EDDE7177988 
Query Result: {"color":"blue","docType":"marble","name":"marble1","owner":"tom","size":35}
2018-01-26 17:51:22.834 UTC [main] main -> INFO 008 Exiting.....
root@370bc984a456:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n marbles -c '{"Args":["getMarblesByRange","marble","marble9"]}'
2018-01-26 17:52:21.753 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2018-01-26 17:52:21.753 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-01-26 17:52:21.753 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 003 Using default escc
2018-01-26 17:52:21.753 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 004 Using default vscc
2018-01-26 17:52:21.753 UTC [chaincodeCmd] getChaincodeSpec -> DEBU 005 java chaincode disabled
2018-01-26 17:52:21.754 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 006 Sign: plaintext: 0AAE070A6A08031A0C08D5D5ADD30510...066D6172626C650A076D6172626C6539 
2018-01-26 17:52:21.754 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 007 Sign: digest: E03478475574EE33CA10C951A3D4CBC7B5F8FEF2F4C2EDC34C039CF4EFC614AD 
Query Result: [{"Key":"marble1", "Record":{"color":"blue","docType":"marble","name":"marble1","owner":"tom","size":35}},{"Key":"marble2", "Record":{"color":"red","docType":"marble","name":"marble2","owner":"tom","size":50}},{"Key":"marble3", "Record":{"color":"blue","docType":"marble","name":"marble3","owner":"tom","size":70}}]
2018-01-26 17:52:21.782 UTC [main] main -> INFO 008 Exiting.....
```

Output of the first two queries on peer0 Org2:

```
root@370bc984a456:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051 CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP" CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n marbles -c '{"Args":["readMarble","marble1"]}'
2018-01-26 17:53:01.507 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2018-01-26 17:53:01.507 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-01-26 17:53:01.508 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 003 Using default escc
2018-01-26 17:53:01.508 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 004 Using default vscc
2018-01-26 17:53:01.509 UTC [chaincodeCmd] getChaincodeSpec -> DEBU 005 java chaincode disabled
2018-01-26 17:53:01.509 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 006 Sign: plaintext: 0AAE070A6A08031A0C08FDD5ADD30510...644D6172626C650A076D6172626C6531 
2018-01-26 17:53:01.510 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 007 Sign: digest: 1D08C870FDC0BE2CC2BE293ABF18BF1EBB73EDEC47425A132DD303DD222B557E 
Query Result: {"color":"blue","docType":"marble","name":"marble1","owner":"tom","size":35}
2018-01-26 17:53:25.592 UTC [main] main -> INFO 008 Exiting.....
root@370bc984a456:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051 CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP" CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n marbles -c '{"Args":["getMarblesByRange","marble","marble9"]}'
2018-01-26 17:53:39.818 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2018-01-26 17:53:39.818 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-01-26 17:53:39.818 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 003 Using default escc
2018-01-26 17:53:39.818 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 004 Using default vscc
2018-01-26 17:53:39.818 UTC [chaincodeCmd] getChaincodeSpec -> DEBU 005 java chaincode disabled
2018-01-26 17:53:39.818 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 006 Sign: plaintext: 0AAE070A6A08031A0C08A3D6ADD30510...066D6172626C650A076D6172626C6539 
2018-01-26 17:53:39.818 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 007 Sign: digest: ACB6855D69BB8609BF5D07997193AC456BE2AACB0E9B9833FEEEA3E1FA944B34 
Query Result: [{"Key":"marble1", "Record":{"color":"blue","docType":"marble","name":"marble1","owner":"tom","size":35}},{"Key":"marble2", "Record":{"color":"red","docType":"marble","name":"marble2","owner":"tom","size":50}},{"Key":"marble3", "Record":{"color":"blue","docType":"marble","name":"marble3","owner":"tom","size":70}}]
2018-01-26 17:53:39.859 UTC [main] main -> INFO 008 Exiting.....
```

Output of the initMarble (marble4) on peer0 Org2.  No error is reported and everything looks good:

```
root@370bc984a456:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051 CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP" CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050  --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n marbles -c '{"Args":["initMarble","marble4","red","40","john"]}'
2018-01-26 17:53:57.895 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2018-01-26 17:53:57.895 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-01-26 17:53:57.913 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 003 Using default escc
2018-01-26 17:53:57.913 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 004 Using default vscc
2018-01-26 17:53:57.913 UTC [chaincodeCmd] getChaincodeSpec -> DEBU 005 java chaincode disabled
2018-01-26 17:53:57.914 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 006 Sign: plaintext: 0AAE070A6A08031A0C08B5D6ADD30510...340A037265640A0234300A046A6F686E 
2018-01-26 17:53:57.914 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 007 Sign: digest: 22F1EBED19D01BB926BC8333D8E6C20D7CEA98D67E3FBDB32A97C052034A42E0 
2018-01-26 17:53:57.946 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 008 Sign: plaintext: 0AAE070A6A08031A0C08B5D6ADD30510...963DE13101C543F98E6EB1DAD7504648 
2018-01-26 17:53:57.947 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 009 Sign: digest: EE16EB383E3F43FFC29004E899F20D2639463A9F13B592454EB202441112B42A 
2018-01-26 17:53:57.979 UTC [chaincodeCmd] chaincodeInvokeOrQuery -> DEBU 00a ESCC invoke result: version:1 response:<status:200 message:"OK" > payload:"\n \035\356\245\202T~!g\217H\243\371\265\212\016t\365|&\032\206\367\352\2240\246\3003\247\236G,\022\303\001\n\253\001\022\027\n\004lscc\022\017\n\r\n\007marbles\022\002\010\003\022\217\001\n\007marbles\022\203\001\n\t\n\007marble4\032\035\n\030\000color~name\000red\000marble4\000\032\001\000\032W\n\007marble4\032L{\"docType\":\"marble\",\"name\":\"marble4\",\"color\":\"red\",\"size\":40,\"owner\":\"john\"}\032\003\010\310\001\"\016\022\007marbles\032\0031.0" endorsement:<endorser:"\n\007Org2MSP\022\222\006-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIICGDCCAb+gAwIBAgIQYknfKWIh8KsyyPE57tFenjAKBggqhkjOPQQDAjBzMQsw\nCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECBMKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTEWMBQGA1UEBxMNU2FuIEZy\nYW5jaXNjbzEZMBcGA1UEChMQb3JnMi5leGFtcGxlLmNvbTEcMBoGA1UEAxMTY2Eu\nb3JnMi5leGFtcGxlLmNvbTAeFw0xODAxMjYxNzQxMzJaFw0yODAxMjQxNzQxMzJa\nMFsxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMwEQYDVQQIEwpDYWxpZm9ybmlhMRYwFAYDVQQHEw1T\nYW4gRnJhbmNpc2NvMR8wHQYDVQQDExZwZWVyMC5vcmcyLmV4YW1wbGUuY29tMFkw\nEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE7SAoZn22uMkwfrDItRK47xRRfkBIZLtN\n2vk1qdTt8IA53g3MjXMkAYeONaJE2BUyfYjhU+ghaZyv153Kzs8EDaNNMEswDgYD\nVR0PAQH/BAQDAgeAMAwGA1UdEwEB/wQCMAAwKwYDVR0jBCQwIoAgQrkMYeoaoiK6\nnRCVankLQpgURiWVC9Av/sxHBo9gBuAwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIDRwAwRAIgJy2H0bV2\nYh788eAEdSu8qxLTO9wZrXDrjjw7HiOIikoCIE1lP0P1Y18W0HWYQ8iva6CyEQd2\noQIsD5MBLlSjMCEP\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n" signature:"0E\002!\000\255\313\361\004=A&\277\270\222\330s\227\014\251\207\324\372\323\321\317\204\026\240\276\312\231\372(\306\367~\002 }\207\333z\0049!WnE\032\2346K\027\364\226=\3411\001\305C\371\216n\261\332\327PFH" > 
2018-01-26 17:53:57.979 UTC [chaincodeCmd] chaincodeInvokeOrQuery -> INFO 00b Chaincode invoke successful. result: status:200 
2018-01-26 17:53:57.979 UTC [main] main -> INFO 00c Exiting.....
```

Output of the second two queries on peer0 Org1.  The new marble4 is not found.  It does not exist in any couchdb either:

```
root@370bc984a456:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n marbles -c '{"Args":["readMarble","marble1"]}'
2018-01-26 17:54:32.695 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2018-01-26 17:54:32.695 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-01-26 17:54:32.695 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 003 Using default escc
2018-01-26 17:54:32.695 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 004 Using default vscc
2018-01-26 17:54:32.696 UTC [chaincodeCmd] getChaincodeSpec -> DEBU 005 java chaincode disabled
2018-01-26 17:54:32.696 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 006 Sign: plaintext: 0AAE070A6A08031A0C08D8D6ADD30510...644D6172626C650A076D6172626C6531 
2018-01-26 17:54:32.696 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 007 Sign: digest: A057F20C69546CB01ED6E9F858E1CD066BC5FC3476F92BC5A5902E44DEA9E68E 
Query Result: {"color":"blue","docType":"marble","name":"marble1","owner":"tom","size":35}
2018-01-26 17:54:32.799 UTC [main] main -> INFO 008 Exiting.....
root@370bc984a456:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n marbles -c '{"Args":["getMarblesByRange","marble","marble9"]}'
2018-01-26 17:54:44.238 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2018-01-26 17:54:44.238 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-01-26 17:54:44.239 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 003 Using default escc
2018-01-26 17:54:44.239 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 004 Using default vscc
2018-01-26 17:54:44.239 UTC [chaincodeCmd] getChaincodeSpec -> DEBU 005 java chaincode disabled
2018-01-26 17:54:44.239 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 006 Sign: plaintext: 0AAD070A6908031A0B08E4D6ADD30510...066D6172626C650A076D6172626C6539 
2018-01-26 17:54:44.239 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 007 Sign: digest: C2A0ADD3589727D58B7DB1320980CD9F21416B7352E1BFAE8AF35603FB45BE1A 
Query Result: [{"Key":"marble1", "Record":{"color":"blue","docType":"marble","name":"marble1","owner":"tom","size":35}},{"Key":"marble2", "Record":{"color":"red","docType":"marble","name":"marble2","owner":"tom","size":50}},{"Key":"marble3", "Record":{"color":"blue","docType":"marble","name":"marble3","owner":"tom","size":70}}]
2018-01-26 17:54:44.278 UTC [main] main -> INFO 008 Exiting.....
```

Output of the second two queries on peer0 Org2.  The new marble4 is not found.  It does not exist in any couchdb either:

```
root@370bc984a456:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051 CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP" CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n marbles -c '{"Args":["readMarble","marble1"]}'
2018-01-26 17:54:55.967 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2018-01-26 17:54:55.967 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-01-26 17:54:55.968 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 003 Using default escc
2018-01-26 17:54:55.968 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 004 Using default vscc
2018-01-26 17:54:55.968 UTC [chaincodeCmd] getChaincodeSpec -> DEBU 005 java chaincode disabled
2018-01-26 17:54:55.968 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 006 Sign: plaintext: 0AAE070A6A08031A0C08EFD6ADD30510...644D6172626C650A076D6172626C6531 
2018-01-26 17:54:55.968 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 007 Sign: digest: BE24E989B610A67B9ABE249142AA8E986B0BF65F722F850E26E095038529664D 
Query Result: {"color":"blue","docType":"marble","name":"marble1","owner":"tom","size":35}
2018-01-26 17:54:56.001 UTC [main] main -> INFO 008 Exiting.....
root@370bc984a456:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051 CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP" CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt peer chaincode query -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n marbles -c '{"Args":["getMarblesByRange","marble","marble9"]}'
2018-01-26 17:55:05.856 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2018-01-26 17:55:05.856 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-01-26 17:55:05.856 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 003 Using default escc
2018-01-26 17:55:05.856 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 004 Using default vscc
2018-01-26 17:55:05.856 UTC [chaincodeCmd] getChaincodeSpec -> DEBU 005 java chaincode disabled
2018-01-26 17:55:05.857 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 006 Sign: plaintext: 0AAE070A6A08031A0C08F9D6ADD30510...066D6172626C650A076D6172626C6539 
2018-01-26 17:55:05.857 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 007 Sign: digest: B1916904CFD8D2908F9BE2A88986D4B93D299F0647D816A2849A9984F688F81F 
Query Result: [{"Key":"marble1", "Record":{"color":"blue","docType":"marble","name":"marble1","owner":"tom","size":35}},{"Key":"marble2", "Record":{"color":"red","docType":"marble","name":"marble2","owner":"tom","size":50}},{"Key":"marble3", "Record":{"color":"blue","docType":"marble","name":"marble3","owner":"tom","size":70}}]
2018-01-26 17:55:05.893 UTC [main] main -> INFO 008 Exiting.....
```

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by my own mistake.  When I instantiate the chaincode, I have specified the wrong endorsement policy:

```
peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n marbles -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init"]}' -P "OR ('Org0MSP.member','Org1MSP.member')"
```

Org0MSP does not exist and Org2MSP for Org2 is not on the policy.  So, the transaction does not really go through.

The correct policy should be

```
-P "OR ('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member')"
```

After fixing the instantiate command, everything works as expected in both peer0 Org1 and peer0 Org2.

However, why is there no error or exception reported?  If you know how the fabric internal works in this case of mistake, please advise and I will very much appreciate your input.  Thank You!